# uiimage of uiimageview doesn't update before NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I'm replacing an uiimage of uiimageview  before calling NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest, an as a result i don't see the new uiimage.

How i can resolve this?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the UI update happen (from the run loop) before sending your synchronous request. Use NSObject's `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to schedule a method after a (zero) delay. In the method you specify in the selector argument you would send the request.

Answer (score 0):

Make an asynchronous request or move the synchronous request into a separate thread.  You can use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` for simple cases.